# XML namespace missing for parser

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, namespaces

I have to parse a XML where the xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" namespace is missing, so the xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<program>
  <scriptList>
  <script type="StartScript">
    <isUserScript>false</isUserScript>
  </script>
  </scriptList>
</program>
```

but should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<program xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
  <scriptList>
    <script xsi:type="StartScript">
      <isUserScript>false</isUserScript>
    </script>
  </scriptList>
</program>
```

The type attribute ensures the correct subclass e.g.

```
class StartScript : script
{...}
```

The parser is auto generated from an handwritten xsd via $> xsd.exe a.xsd /classes (.Net).
Here is the xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="qualified">

  <!-- Main element -->
  <xs:element name="program">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="scriptList">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="script" type="script" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:complexType name="script" />

  <xs:complexType name="StartScript">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="script">
        <xs:all>
          <xs:element name="isUserScript" type="xs:boolean"></xs:element>
        </xs:all>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
```

A simple solution is to run a string-replace (" type=\"" to " xsi:type=\"") on the input XML but this is pretty ugly.
Is there a better solution?

Comment: How are you parsing it?  Are you using `XmlSerializer`, or something else?  Are there other types of `script` or only `StartScript`?

Comment: Parsing is simple in C#: 
_program = (new XmlSerializer(typeof(program))).Deserialize(f) as program;

There are a lot of scripts, StartScript s just one example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load your XML into an intermediate [LINQ to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) [`XDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), fix the attribute namespaces on the `<script>` elements, then deserialize directly to your final class:

```
// Load to intermediate XDocument
XDocument xDoc;
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(f))
    xDoc = XDocument.Load(reader);

// Fix namespace of "type" attributes
XNamespace xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
foreach (var element in xDoc.Descendants("script"))
{
    var attr = element.Attribute("type");
    if (attr == null)
        continue;
    var newAttr = new XAttribute(xsi + attr.Name.LocalName, attr.Value);
    attr.Remove();
    element.Add(newAttr);
}

// Deserialize directly to final class.
var program = xDoc.Deserialize<program>();
```

Using the extension method:

```
public static class XObjectExtensions
{
    public static T Deserialize<T>(this XContainer element, XmlSerializer serializer = null)
    {
        if (element == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        using (var reader = element.CreateReader())
            return (T)(serializer ?? new XmlSerializer(typeof(T))).Deserialize(reader);
    }
}
```